# Rikulo Stream serve specified file

Tags: stream, dart, rikulo

How do I serve a file that I specify in Rikulo stream without doing a redirect. I was trying

```
new ResourceLoader('my_app').load(connect, 'alternate.html');
```

from the plugin package but I receive the error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Path' of 'rootDir'

Comment: try to replace the string 'my_app' with an object path that somehow contains the string.

Comment: thanks, was sleeping on that one!

Comment: np, i posted my comment as answer too. So it can be closed.

Comment: A bit off of topic, you can consider [connect.include or forward](http://docs.rikulo.org/stream/latest/Request_and_Response/Request_Forwarding_and_Inclusion.html) to loop back the server for serving a static resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the string 'my_app' with an object path that somehow contains the string.